# How am I supposed to approach this problem?

Tags: integration

Problem: The Cobb-Douglas production function for an automobile manufacturer is 
$$f(x,y)=100x^{.6}y^{.4} $$
Where x is the number of units of labor and y is the number of units of capital. Estimate the average production level if the number of units of labor x varies between 200 and 240 and the number of units of capital y varies between 300 and 330.

Comment: Search up "average value of a function of 2 variables"

Comment: So should I set it up like this: 
\int _{200}^{240}\int _{300}^{330}\:\:\:100x^{.6}y^{.4}\:dxdy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average value of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$  over a region $R$ is given by:
$$
\frac{1}{A(R)}\int_R f(x,y)dA
$$

in your case the region is the rectangle defined by: $200<x<240$ and $300<y<330$; so the area is $A(R)= 1200$ and the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{1200}\int_{300}^{330}\int_{200}^{240}100\; x^{0.6}y^{0.4} dx dy
$$

Comment: thanks for the help! ;^^

Comment: You  are welcome! And don't forget to accept the answer if you like it ..:)